# 0MQ windows GUI best practice

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, zeromq

I've a pretty simple question/issue.  I want to use 0MQ for some pretty basic Pub/sub functionality.  My subscriber app is a windows GUI based app using plain winforms.

As there seems to be no explicit reference in 0MQ for handling this scenario, I am assuming that worst case I'd have to use a BeginInvoke(...) on the windows GUI thread once the 0MQ thread has recieved any subscription message.  This seems pretty straightforward but if anyone has any insight/opinion/heads up in terms of the best way to handle this I'd very much appreciate it.

Thanks in advance
David

Comment: more information would help in discerning what you're looking for.  I'm not sure if you're referencing the built-in 0mq Context background thread or your own thread that does 0mq stuff. 

Normally with 0mq, you create a context and each thread in your code gets its own socket (all built from one context which you share across thread boundaries, its thread safe). Then you can either block on a send/recv of a socket or setup a zmq_poll object to poll when a socket has messages available...

Answer (score 1):

For your ZeroMQ subscriber in a WinForms application you have at least a few options:

1. Use a background worker thread to receive your 0MQ message. When you receive a message pass it to your background worker `progressChanged` event to update your UI.
2. Use a system thread to receive the message and invoke to update your UI.
3. Another suggestion on SO also suggest using a system thread to queue the message upon receive and a timer event to dequeue the message. If you used a Forms Timer you could update the UI without invoking or if System Timer you would need an invoke.

Which method you choose depends on your design criteria.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, there are several ways to hook up ZeroMq into a WinForms app. It really does not differ much from using ZeroMq and C# in other settings, like in a console application. The main difference is as you point out that you have to get the messages into the Gui thread in order to update your Gui controls.

An example of using a separate thread + queues (producer/consumer pattern) can be found here: [Examples of zeromq pub/sub with C# winform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794393/examples-of-zeromq-pub-sub-with-c-sharp-winform/14797475#14797475)

Another way could be to use (again) a separate thread to do the ZeroMq work and set up an event that gets fired each time a message is received. The Gui could then hook up an event handler and process the message. You would of course also have to invoke any updates to the Gui. A drawback to this approach is that the event processing will interfere with the ZeroMq handler thread a bit, especially if the Gui updates takes a while, and if you receive lots of data.

All solutions have their pros and cons, it all depends on how your particular problem domain looks. All-in-all, integrating ZeroMq into a C# application, be it WinForms or other, is IMO pretty straightforward. The [clrzmq wrapper](https://github.com/zeromq/clrzmq) is well-written and easy to use. The problems you may run into has more to do with the limited error feedback in ZeroMq itself. If you encounter strange crashes; try to run the same logic in a console application, that will give you better error messages.