# while(1) loop freezes GUI where C# winform attempts to receive strings endlessly over ZMQ from Python script

Tags: c#, python, multithreading, winforms, zeromq

Objective is click of button should start populating textbox with strings received from python script. In debug stepping I get to see the strings being received in "var message". But by virtue of `while(true)`, the GUI freezes and one never gets to see textbox contents.

Tried Backgroundworker, but it throws exception for no access to richTextBox2.

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = ZmqContext.Create())
        {
            using (ZmqSocket SubscriberSocket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.SUB))
            {
                SubscriberSocket.Subscribe(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("220.20"));
                SubscriberSocket.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");
                while(true)
                {
                  var message = SubscriberSocket.Receive(Encoding.UTF8);
                  richTextBox2.Text += message + '\n';
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use Backgroundworker + Control.BeginInvoke

Answer (score 0):

It is not a clear solution, but it should work

```
public delegate void updateTextBoxDelegate(string textBoxString);
public updateTextBoxDelegate updateTextBox;

void updateTextBox1(string message) { richTextBox2.Text = message + '\n'; }

void UpdatetextBox(string strItem)
{
    if (richTextBox2.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(this.updateTextBox, strItem);
    }
}
```

And then update your button4_Click

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var context = ZmqContext.Create())
        {
            using (ZmqSocket SubscriberSocket = context.CreateSocket(SocketType.SUB))
            {
                SubscriberSocket.Subscribe(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("220.20"));
                SubscriberSocket.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");
                while(true)
                {
                  var message = SubscriberSocket.Receive(Encoding.UTF8);
                  UpdatetextBox(message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Slava, somehow I managed it as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794393/examples-of-zeromq-pub-sub-with-c-sharp-winform/14797475#14797475