# Call Join for multiple threads simultaneously

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am writing a script in C# for Unity to read messages from multiple sources. I have a function `ReadMessage` which takes in a port string and returns a string ID number. The issue is, I have a dozen different connections I need to read from and the messages have a 10ms timeout timer before it stops trying and lets the code continue. This causes a reduction in frame rate when I have a dozen threads waiting a few ms for the previous one to finish Joining. My thread code is as follows:

```
string threadOneString= null;
Thread ThreadOne;
//Repeat for 11 more threads
void Update () {
    ThreadOne = new Thread(
        () =>
        {
            threadOneString = ReadMessage(someClass.port);
        });
    ThreadOne.Start();
//Repeat for 11 more threads
}

void LateUpdate () {
    ThreadOne.Join();
    //Repeat for 11 more threads

    UpdateClass(threadOneString);
    //Repeat for 11 more threads

    UpdateTextDisplay(); //Just updates a Unity Text object
}
```

And my `ReadMessage` code in case it matters.

```
private string ReadMessage(string port) //Change this name to ReadButtonPress
    {
        string fullMessage = "";
        someStruct parsedMessage;
        var timeout = new System.TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10); // Less than 10 and it starts to miss most messages, ideally this would be a bit higher
        string connectionString = PROTOCOL + CONTROLLER_IP + ":" +  port;

        AsyncIO.ForceDotNet.Force();     
        using (var subSocket = new SubscriberSocket())
        {
            subSocket.Connect(connectionString);
            subSocket.Subscribe("");

            subSocket.TryReceiveFrameString(timeout, out fullMessage);
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Message: " + fullMessage);

            subSocket.Close();
        }
    // Some message parsing and checking...
    return parsedMessage.someString;
}
```

What I'd like to do, but I don't know if it's possible, is to call the Joins for each thread at the same time instead of calling one, waiting, then calling the next. The threads don't interact with each other, so I'm hoping this is possible. If not, I'd greatly appreciate another solution or suggestion.

EDIT: Clarification on what's happening. When I only run a few threads I get a FPS of 65-70. When I run all 12 threads my FPS drops to ~50 and I have a hard requirement of 60 FPS.

Comment: You could use `Task`s and `Task.WhenAll` ... Is there any reason not to use TPL ?

Comment: Logically, it shouldn't make much difference. When you're not doing anything to actively try to make the thread exit sooner, then `Thread.Join` will either encounter a thread that has already exited which *should* be relatively fast or it just has to wait for that thread to exit. Once it's done that wait for *one* thread, if they should all be taking the same amount of time to run, then you'd *expect* that every other `Join` will be the fast case where the next thread had already exited. And if it hasn't, you'd expect "multi-Join" to still have to wait for the thread(s) that are running late

Comment: @Fabjan The version of Unity I'm using only supports up to .NET 3.5 and if I remember correctly Task wasn't added until 4.0

Comment: Why are you `.Join`ing at all?  You are repeating everything 12 times.  Just respond to .WhenAll event as other folks mentioned  In addition, the `threadOneString` variable will be in contention since you are overwriting it from every thread. This code needs to be re-fengshui-ed.

Comment: @AngryHacker There are 12 separate Threads ex: ThreadOne, ThreadTwo, ThreadThree, etc. I just didn't want to keep writing it out a dozen times

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Unity, but `SubscriberSocket` *sounds* like something that you ought to be able to keep around for a while, not something you should be creating and disposing of all of the time. Is it really the intended use case that you connect/subscribe/receive *one frame* and then close?

Comment: I'm quite sure it all can be done in a better way, without starting 12 threads and opening some socket connection 12 times, all that every frame. Join all threads at once is unlikely to help here.

Comment: You could create an extension method `WhenAll` for Threads yourself. Here is an [example.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/bdhPmo)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to some feedback here I am no longer creating a socket every update. Instead I create the sockets in `Start()` and just read what I need from a public function in the class. I based my code on https://stackoverflow.com/a/14797475/8635796

Don't do what I did and recreate the exact same threads and sockets every `Update()`. In hindsight, it was a really poor choice.

Answer (score -1):

Use tasks instead, and put them into a list.

```
var myTasks = new List<Task>();
Task allUpdateTasks;
...
void Update () {
    myTasks.Add(
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            threadOneString = ReadMessage(someClass.port);
        }));
//Repeat for 11 more tasks

// Create a single tasks that will hold all tasks above.
allUpdateTasks = Task.WhenAll(myTasks);
}

void LateUpdate() {
    allUpdateTasks.Wait();
...
}
```

Comment: The version of Unity I'm using only supports up to .NET 3.5, so I don't think I can use Task. If I could use .NET 4.0 or above this would probably be the correct answer.

Comment: Are you be able to update your Unity? Checkout this link https://forum.unity.com/threads/upgraded-mono-net-in-editor-on-5-5-0b4.433541/

Answer (score -1):

define ManualResetEvent and signal it when you got results, you can wait up to 64 waithandles using WaitHandle.WaitAny